# Can transformer network be used as one-to-many structure?

Tags: networking, transformer-model

I want to replace one-to-many LSTM into transformer network, so I am studying it right now.
But as far as I studied, the transformer network uses Encoder-Decoder structure, which is mapping the input components with the output components.

Is it possible to use this encoder-decoder structure with one-to-many structure like LSTM?
If this is possible, then we are connecting all the "many" parts with the "one" vector and training them. Is it correct?

Comment: You can always feed/append the output of the previous step to the model to get new input.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but yes, you can use transformer for many-to-one structure. You don't need both the encoder and decoder in every application. A straightforward way to achieve many-to-one is using only the encoder + positional encoder. Then at the end, where you have multiple output vectors, you can apply any aggregation operation (like sum, mean, etc.) to get a single representational vector for the whole sequence of input. Connect it to your classifier or regressor to do whatever you want.